# Notation for repeating the concatenation operation

Tags: notation, soft-question

Let $X_1, X_2, …, X_n$ be tuples. For tuples $X$ and $Y$, define $X\cdot  Y$ as the concatenation of $X$ and $Y$.

Is it okay for me to use $\Pi_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}$ to express the concatenation of $X_1\cdot X_2\cdot \dots \cdot X_n$? If not, are there other notations for describing this process?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2):

The answer to whether "it is okay" for you to express concatenation like that is always "yes". It's okay for you to do anything as long as you explain yourself. No one is stopping you from saying "In this section, the following will be the notation for concatenation and there will be no ambiguity since we will not deal with numbers being multiplied.". You can definitely say stuff like that and then you're allowed to use that notation.

There will be some people who like your choice of notation. There will be some who hate it. It's part of what makes the subject so interesting; preferences over certain bits of notation can create differences in the way that people view a given theory. These differences make the subject interesting.

Now, of course, there are a few unspoken rules about this stuff; you shouldn't be obnoxious and if your notation is ambiguous, the ambiguity should not affect the way in which it is interpreted for everything that actually matters in a given book or set of notes. People tend to try and follow these general guidelines.

As for your second question, I've seen $A^\frown B$ being used to denote concatenation. I've also seen $A || B$ being used to denote concatenation too, though I'd imagine that these wouldn't be super suitable for speaking easily about the concatenation of $n$ elements.